# Help "xpdf" search for wrapped text?

Tags: pdf, search

I am using `xpdf` 4.04 on Cygwin.  When I use Ctrl+F to find a wrapped text, it doesn't find it (but it does find instances of the text that isn't wrapped).  For example, if I search for "quick brown fox", `xpdf` will find occurrences in the PDF showing up as shown in the 1st paragraph below, but not the 2nd one:

```
The quick brown fox jumped
over the lazy dogs.

I doubt that the quick brown
fox jumped over the lazy dogs.
```

In contrast, PhantomPDF will find wrapped and unwrapped instances of the same text in the same PDF file.  I don't want to use PhantomPDF, however, as it locks the PDF file.  For LaTeX, I am constantly overwriting the file.

Is there anything that can be done to allow `xpdf` to find wrapped text?

Comment: Clarification question: by "wrapped" you mean hyphenated, i.e., the first part of a word ending with a hyphen on one line and the second part of that word on the next line (like in- [new line] stances)?

Comment: @Marijn: I mean that a newline occurs where there is white space in the phrase of interest.  I added an example to the originally posted question.  Thanks for prompting that clarification.